# Tinymce setcontent a link an selected img

Tags: javascript, tinymce

In Tinymce I select an image. I would like to create a link with this:

```
var code = window.opener.tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
window.opener.tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent(code);
```

but it doesn't work.

If i select a text then work correctly!

Please help me i dont understand that why?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here wont't work because you just get the selection context and set it to this context - so nothing changes!

A solution approach:

```
var code = window.opener.tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
window.opener.tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent(code + "<a href='http://mydomain/xxx.png'>Link</a>");
```